# New synonym to violin tag: fiddle

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Could someone make/suggest ***fiddle*** as synonym tag to [violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/violin/info).

I don't have enough reputation points and its quite common sense that violin is called fiddle often, and *fiddle* means *violin* in what concerns the physical aspects and its construction.

The difference between fiddle and violin is only that they are called different things depending on which musical context they are in. Classical music uses only *violin*, other genres uses both or just *fiddle*.

Thank you!

Comment: There may come a time when the site has so many questions that it's worth delinking these two concepts, but for now, I think it's best to have done so.